# Launch new instance when there is no instance open on current workspace

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, multiple-instances

I am struggling with organizing my workspaces. I have one workspace per Project I am working on. Some applications I can fix to a single workspace, since they are only needed for a single project. Others (like Firefox) I need on all workspaces.
Now, when I open Firefox from a workspace that does not have a Firefox instance in it, I am either taken to a workspace with a Firefox instance or a new Firefox instance is launched.

How can I always launch a new instance, when there is none in the current workspace? Turning on the "Launch new instance" plugin in gnome-tweaks launches new instances even if there is an instance open in the current workspace.

Basically, when I open Firefox (or any application that is not fixed to a workspace), I want the following to happen:
Is there an instance running in the current workspace? -> Give focus to that instance
Otherwise, launch a new instance in the current workspace.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How are you launching Firefox for example?

Comment: By pressing super and searching for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to "*isolate*" your current workspace. You can do that by using the [Workspace Isolated Dash](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/887/workspace-isolated-dash/) GNOME shell extension for example. However, since Ubuntu nowadays (version 17.10 and later) comes with Ubuntu Dock (a fork of Dash to Dock), you can activate this by simply running the following command in Terminal, no need to do anything extra:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces true
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you very much!

Comment: This doesn't work for me in 20.04.3. dash-to-dock/isolate-workspaces, window-switcher/current-workspace-only, and app-switcher/current-workspace-only are all set to true. Still get taken to another workspace if there is no document open in this one. Any suggestions for futher troubleshooting?

Comment: Also, if I click on a link in Thunderbird in one workspace, it will open it in an already-open Firefox window in another workspace.

Answer (score 3):

### dconf-editor

in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS,
`dconf-editor` seems powerful (than `gnome-tweaks`)
and easy to use (than `gsettings` or `dconf`).

the workspace related options:

- /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/isolate-workspaces
- /org/gnome/shell/app-switcher/current-workspace-only
- /org/gnome/shell/window-switcher/current-workspace-only

Run `dconf-editor`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to input location path.

screenshot:

[image: dconf-editor.png]

Answer (score 0):

We need, [Launch new instance](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/600/launch-new-instance/) and [dash to panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) extensions.

Then we need to set:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-panel isolate-workspaces true
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

This might not work for some applications unless you edit the `.desktop` for those apps as shown bellow.

Before that, please check: [Launch New Instance: Not working on Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome on Xorg](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions/-/issues/67).

> sublime has a "New Window" desktop action, but it's not recognized as that by gnome-shell because it doesn't use `new-window` as identifier.

So, for example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=VSCodium
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/usr/share/codium/codium --unity-launch %F
Icon=vscodium
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=VSCodium
Categories=TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;application/x-codium-workspace;
Actions=new-empty-window;
Keywords=vscode;

[Desktop Action new-empty-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/usr/share/codium/codium --new-window %F
Icon=vscodium
```

Here, Look at the action identifier in `Actions=new-empty-window;` which is `new-empty-window`. **It does not work**. We have to copy the `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` and then replace `new-empty-window` with `new-window` and then run `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications` (then we may have to restart the gnome session using <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> → <kbd>r</kbd> →<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

For some applications there might be no actions at all. For example, fsearch.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=FSearch
Comment=A file search application focusing on performance and advanced features
Icon=io.github.cboxdoerfer.FSearch
TryExec=fsearch
Exec=fsearch
Categories=GTK;Utility;Core;
Keywords=search;fsearch;files;folders;music;video;documents;find;tool;everything;
StartupNotify=true
```

In this case we have to edit the file like bellow:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=FSearch
Comment=A file search application focusing on performance and advanced features
Icon=io.github.cboxdoerfer.FSearch
TryExec=fsearch
Exec=fsearch
Categories=GTK;Utility;Core;
Keywords=search;fsearch;files;folders;music;video;documents;find;tool;everything;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=new-window;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=fsearch --new-window
Icon=io.github.cboxdoerfer.FSearch
```

Please notice that I have added `Actions=new-window;` under `[Desktop Entry]` and then added `[Desktop Action new-window]`

Hope this helps.