# How to make workspaces truly separate in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: workspaces

I use workspaces to separate the different things I am working on. However, often when I open a link in one workspace I jump to another workspace and this kinda defeats the purpose of keeping these things separate, because now different topics get mixed in a certain workspace.
Is there a way to keep workspaces truly separate on Ubuntu 22.04?
By truly separate, I mean that opening an application (browser, pdfviewer) doesn´t change workspace (even an instance of the needed app already runs in another workspace).

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162628/launch-new-instance-when-there-is-no-instance-open-on-current-workspace

Comment: What is your desktop environment?

Comment: I am using GNOME

Comment: @MaximilianBallard Thanks for the link, but none of the fixes actually work for me.